# Compiling OpenSSL

Tags: visual-c++, openssl

I have followed all instructions of INSTALL.W32. I don't want to use ms\do_nasm as it is optional. I have my ntdll make file in ms. I am stil getting following error.

> NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'ms\ntdll.mak' not found Stop.

Please someone help me.

Comment: Paste the full console log.

Comment: Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'ms\ntdll.mak' not found
Stop.

Comment: Full - from the first command (included) onwards.

Comment: C:\openssl>perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=c:\openssl1
Configuring for VC-WIN32
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)

Comment: no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default]
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
IsMK1MF=1
CC            =cl

Comment: CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -W3 -Gs0 -GF -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL
_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DOPE
NSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_AS
M_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DV
PAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
EX_LIBS  
     =
CPUID_OBJ     =x86cpuid.o
BN_ASM        =bn-586.o co-586.o x86-mont.o x86-gf2m.o
DES_ENC       =des-586.o crypt586.o
AES_ENC       =aes-586.o vpaes-x86.o aesni-x86.o

Comment: RANLIB        =true
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =perl
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode
RC4_INDEX mode
RC4_CHUNK is undefine
Configured for VC-WIN32.
C:\openssl>perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm --prefix=c:/openssl1

Comment: RANLIB        =true
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =perl
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode
RC4_INDEX mode
RC4_CHUNK is undefine
Configured for VC-WIN32.
C:\openssl>perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm --prefix=c:/openssl1

Comment: Configuring for VC-WIN32
    no-asm          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_ASM
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default]

Comment: no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
IsMK1MF=1
CC            =cl
CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -W3 -Gs0 -GF -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL
_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
EX_LIBS       =
CPUID_OBJ     =mem_clr.o

Comment: BN_ASM        =bn_asm.o
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes_core.o aes_cbc.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4_enc.o rc4_skey.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=

Comment: CMLL_ENC      =camellia.o cmll_misc.o cmll_cbc.o
MODES_OBJ     =
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =true
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =perl
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode
RC4_INDEX mode
RC4_CHUNK is undefined
Configured for VC-WIN32.

Comment: C:\openssl>ms\do_ms

C:\openssl>perl util\mkfiles.pl  1>MINFO

C:\openssl>perl util\mk1mf.pl no-asm VC-WIN32  1>ms\nt.mak

C:\openssl>perl util\mk1mf.pl dll no-asm VC-WIN32  1>ms\ntdll.mak



C:\openssl>if x == x goto skipce

C:\openssl>perl util\mkdef.pl 32 libeay  1>ms\libeay32.def

C:\openssl>perl util\mkdef.pl 32 ssleay  1>ms\ssleay32.def

C:\openssl